# Create a column with a value from data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset:

[image]

I want to create a column with the value from the date. In this example, it is 201201, but the excel may have a different date. So I do not want to create a date by writing 201201, rather than create a link between the column and date. The output should look like:

[image]

I appreciate any assistance you can provide me.

Comment: Please use dput to show the example instead of images

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you have a data frame in R, similar to a worksheet in Excel. I'll just create one for demonstration purposes:

```
> data <- data.frame(Name=c("A","B","C"), books=c(3,5,8))
> data
  Name books
1    A     3
2    B     5
3    C     8
```

Now I will create a scalar of class "Date", similar to the value in your cell D1:

```
> Date <- as.Date("2001-12-20")
> Date
[1] "2001-12-20"
```

Now I will create a new column in data corresponding to this date:

```
> data$Date <- Date
> data
  Name books       Date
1    A     3 2001-12-20
2    B     5 2001-12-20
3    C     8 2001-12-20
```

Is that what you had in mind?

**Edit**: To import the date value from only cell D1 in an Excel file called "Report.xlsx" (<strike>to automatize</strike> <strike>automaterize</strike> to make the process run with less human intervention):

```
> library(readxl)
> Report <- read_excel("E:/Book1.xlsx", range="D1", col_names="today", col_types = "text")
> Report %>% mutate(today=as.Date(today, format="%y%m%d"))
```

Comment: Hi Edward, thank you for your reply. It is not what I have in mind. I want the column to take any value in cell D1. In this example, it is 201201, but next report I will receive will have 201202 in cell D1. So I do not want to populate the column manually, instead of creating a link with the column and cell D1. Do you have any idea about that? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking then. You want to do this in R or in Excel??

Comment: In R. I want to automatize the cleaning and transformation process. I could create a date column manually, which will disrupt the automation process.  The value I want to put into the column is in one cell, so I want to "copy" the cell value to the whole new column.

Comment: So import the D1 cell into an R Date object using the read_excel function from the readxl package and specify range="D1".  You may have to format it correctly using as.Date(d1, format="%y%m%d") or whatever format the dates are entered.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Sorry, I do not get your idea. It seems that the process could be done during the process of reading the data. Is there any code to import the D1 cell? Thanks again!